# Prony method for frequency estimation in matlab

Tags: signal-analysis, estimation

i am interested  if where can i find matlab code for  Prony method for frequency estimation.there is  pdf article  about prony 
https://www.google.ge/#site=&source=hp&q=prony+method+for+distorted+signal&oq=prony+method+for+distorted+signal&gs_l=hp.3...2187.8079.0.8365.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.ernk_timediscountc..0.0...1.1.16.hp.enCwRCZuhe0&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.bGE&fp=79e233fb1755afd8&biw=1280&bih=675
first one is   about  prony.so what i ant is that for given  signal,prony  method should return Amplitudes,damping factor and phase shift and also this parameters should minimize  sum of squared error.in matlab webpase there is prony for filter design,but i think  this  method is not what i am looking for,please  could  you help  how to find code for prony method in matlab?

Comment: Why don't you just use the signal processing toolbox method [`prony`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/prony.html) ?

Comment: is that same?as i  understand it  does different job

Comment: Any parametric form of frequency estimation is trying to find the "filter" transfer function $H(z)$ that best approximates the signal's spectrum.  You need to then extract the frequencies from $H(z)$.

Comment: and location of peaks is used yes to find  frequencies

Comment: Yes, that's correct... though it's not as easy as it sounds. :-)